# vb.net treeview containskey

Tags: vb.net, treeview

i try do code for dont duplicate treeview nodes.

My code:

```
If TreeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey("AAA") Then
     MsgBox("have")
Else
     TreeView1.Nodes.Add("AAA")
End If
```

and just ADD and dont say "have"

my code before this:

```
Using Comm As New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(Conn)
                    Comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM trabalhos WHERE matricula='" + MaskedTextBox1.Text + "' ORDER BY data DESC;"

                    Dim Adapter As New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter(Comm)
                    Dim DataTable As New System.Data.DataTable()
                    Adapter.Fill(DataTable)
                    For Each Row As DataRow In DataTable.Rows

                        If TreeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey("AAA") Then
                            MsgBox("have")
                        Else
                            TreeView1.Nodes.Add("AAA")

                        End If

                    Next
                End Using
```

thanks for help.

Comment: You're not adding the nodes with keys in the first place so there's no matching key in the collection.  Read the documentation for that `Add` method that you're calling and see what overloads it has. The text on the node is NOT the key.

Comment: humm okey, i go will try ty

Comment: dam to easy xDD thanks for help!
solution: TreeView1.Nodes.Add("AAA", "AAA")